# Execution of the command buffer was aborted/GPU Error when saving images to disk using Metal Framework

Tags: swift, arkit, metal

I am working on an IOS app (ios 12) that uses both the ARKit and Metal/Metal Kit Frameworks. I am capturing images and zipping them and saving them to the phone's document directory. The images are being captured every 10 centimeters the phone moves. However, after about 10 minutes (after about 300 MB of data is saved) the app crashes and spits the error:

> "Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Discarded (victim of GPU error/recovery) (IOAF code 5)"

Has anyone seen this or understand what may be the issue?

Comment: I have this as well, and I have found no answers and it's extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Change your background property of mainscene from procedural sky to custom image and turn off environment[sceen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEhQM.png)